# Touch within view only- android

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I am trying to do this but it gave me headache
I have a view that draw a color bar. And I want to allow user to move it around (drag and drop)

this is on draw method:

```
int r,g,b;
        for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        {       
            r =  Math.round((float)colorBuffer[i][0]*MAX_SCALING);
            g =  Math.round((float)colorBuffer[i][1]*MAX_SCALING);
            b =  Math.round((float)colorBuffer[i][2]*MAX_SCALING);
            paint.setColor(Color.argb(MAX_SCALING, r, g, b));

            canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y1, paint);
            y1+=3;
        }
```

rgb is just the color.

this is my ontouch implementation.

```
     public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) 
        {
            float x = e.getX();
            float y = e.getY();

            switch (e.getAction()) 
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                {
                    Toast t = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Touch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    t.show();
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                {
                    x1=(int) x;
                    x2=(int) (x+30);
                    y1=(int) y;
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                {
                    Toast t = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Release", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    t.show();
                    x1=(int) x;
                    x2=(int) (x+30);
                    y1=(int) y;
                    break;
                }

            }
            invalidate();
            return true;  



}
```

this works perfectly fine, but the problem is that it works even outside the view. 
so if i touch outsite the view my bar move over there too
even when i click a button my bar try to move too
I want to drag and drop the component only if the user touch within the view

any help would be appreciate
thanks

Answer (score 0):

On touch get the x, y, width, and height of your view. Then every time when you are moving the bar, as I understand in `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`, check if current coordinates are whithin the views's bounds, if this is true, then allow to move the bar.